# Clearing a pseudo element on Android browser

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, android-browser

I am adding a dark shadow (as a before element) to a div on touch/click And removing it after the effect is done.

First click seems to be fine but on subsequent clicks, the effects gets darker and darker (until it gets to complete black).

It is as if there are multiple layers of before's

The only solution I have found so far it to setup the div's display property as "display: block" but this required me to do some layout rework.  Any other suggestions ?

Here is the class I am using to set the highlight

```
.myDivCls:before
{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
opacity: .3;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

And her is the one for removing it:

```
.noEffectCls:before {
content: '';
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
position: static;
border-radius: 0;
background-size: auto auto;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0% 0%;
-webkit-background-size: auto auto;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `display:inline-block` ?

Comment: Thanks @GionaF. I am trying to avoid having to change the display property. Is is currently set to table and any changes in that will mean I will have to restructure my CSS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a the background shorthand prooperty on the .noEffectCls:before element and setting it to transparent?